# Puppet paste multiple variables into one

Tags: puppet

For example i have from `1` to `n` variables in array.I took `3` for Examples as

```
$one = "1"
$two = "2"
$three = "3"
$var =  [ "$one", "two", "three" ]
```

I need to paste this `3` vars into one. Only content.

```
$resultvar = "123"
```

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18526579/2032064)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean concatenate just three variables:

```
$resultvar = "${one}${two}${three}"
```

If you need array elements of variable size, you could use an inline template:

```
$resultvar = inline_template('<% arrayvar.each { |i| -%> <%= i -%> <% } %>')
```