# How to convert array to comma separated string in Puppet 2.7

Tags: puppet

I am using Puppet 2.7 and I need to convert an array to comma separated list.

```
$hosts_fqdn= ['host1','host2','host3']
```

And I need to convert it to desired result: `'host1,host2,host3'`

I guess that Puppet 3.2 offers lambda expression - `reduce`. But unfortunately that is not possible with 2.7.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the reduce expression. It is very useful where you want to have multiple words joining the elements of array and not just commas or symbols.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Function `join` from [puppetlabs/stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib):

```
join($hosts_fqdn,',')
```